# Angular select class if else

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I need to select a class when the index is equal to the length. I have this:

```
<ion-row  *ngFor="let p of order.lines; let i = index" [ngClass]="order.lines.length == i? 'rowProductsf' : 'rowProducts'">
```

Comment: What's your problem? What's the surrounding code? What have you tried to fix the issue so far?

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition to `[ngClass]="order.lines.length-1 == i` because `index` start from 0, also you miss typo `ngClass`

```js
<ion-row  *ngFor="let p of order.lines; let i = index" [ngClass]="order.lines.length-1 == i? 'rowProductsf' : 'rowProducts'">
```